# Bind SignalR IHubContext to Ninject kernel in net core 2.1

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, signalr, ninject

I'm using NET Core 2.1 and have Ninject as my DI and I'm trying to inject ***IHubContext*** inside a controller constructor using ninject, but getting this error:

"*Ninject.ActivationException: 'Error activating IHubContext No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.*"

I've added SignalR to services (*services.AddSignalR()*) and mapped it for the IApplicationBuilder: 
 *app.UseSignalR(route => route.MapHub("/myhub"));*

Tried binding it from the global resolver also: *kernel.Bind< IHubContext>().ToMethod(context => GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve< IHubContext>()).InSingletonScope();* but with no luck, what I am missing in order to inject this IHubContext in the constructor of my controller using Ninject.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be binding `IHubContext<THub>`. I'm assuming your `MapHub` is actually `MapHub<HubType>`, you should use `HubType` with `IHubContext<>`

Answer (score 2):

Finally fixed this issue, for anyone else who has this problem, trying to use signalR with Ninject as the DI.

```
 var serviceProvider = app.ApplicationServices;
 kernel.Bind<IHubContext<MyHub>>().ToMethod(context => serviceProvider.GetService<IHubContext<MyHub>>());
```